# Mixing pointers to allocated objects and scoped objects

Tags: c++

What if I have a map that points to objects that are supposed to be allocated, but some other caller inserts a pointer to an object that will go out of scope? Considering you can add object pointers in two ways:

```
class MyClass {
    public:
        std::map<int, MyObject*> myMap;
        MyClass();
        ~MyClass();
};
MyClass::MyClass(){}
MyClass::~MyClass(){
    std::map<int, MyObject*>::iterator it;
    for(it = this->myMap.begin(); it != this->myMap.end(); it++){
        delete it->second;
    }
}
```

Case 1 - by reference for objects that will go out of scope

```
MyObject myObject;
ptrMyClass->myMap.insert(std::make_pair(0, &myObject));
```

Case 2 - by allocated objects

```
MyObject myObject = new MyObject();
ptrMyClass->myMap.insert(std::make_pair(0, myObject));
```

Is it sensible to do this?

```
for(it = this->myMap.begin(); it != this->myMap.end(); it++){
     if(sizeof(it->second) == sizeof(MyObject)){
         delete it->second;
     }
 }
```

It will at least avoid a memory free error, and if I clear at the end, does it cover all cases? Is it possible to avoid this situation in the first place? (I use C++98)

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. Case 1 is invalid (you seem to know this) and case 2 won't compile. "Sensible" to what end? What are you trying to do?

Comment: Your solution will not work, even if it works in your tests.  You'll need to decide if your `map` is going to own the `MyObject`s or not.  If you want to avoid objects going out of scope, I'd have it store `MyObject`s directly (not pointers).

Comment: What is a `memory free error`? If you mean the *undefined behavior* that is invoked by calling `delete` on an invalid pointer, then no, you won't avoid it this way. Also your check simply cannot work

Comment: Are you trying to _detect_ when someone inserted a dangling pointer into your map? Because you simply can't. Tell people not do it and move on.

Comment: Use smart pointers. That's what they're for.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Yes I guess so.. My senior programmers tell me to check all incoming variables, so I feel like I have to check for everything.

Comment: @sturcotte06 I explicitly said I am using C++98 I don't have smart pointers.

Comment: Then make one. Unique pointers are very easy to implement.

Comment: You can use boost smart pointers, or store a `std::pair<MyObject*,bool>` and set it to `true` if you do own the object.

Comment: @ICU_: _"My senior programmers tell me to check all incoming variables, so I feel like I have to check for everything"_ Okay. Well, defensive programming is not necessarily a bad thing in some cases, but (a) there are times you just _can't_ (like now), and (b) there are times you _shouldn't_ (a fast function in a tight loop should document preconditions, not execute many branches to verify the inputs). Ultimately it's a balancing act.

Comment: @sturcotte06: Unique pointers are almost impossible to implement in C++98. That's why `std::auto_ptr` was so bad that it was later removed from the language.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Can you not implement it with a mock xvalue like `template<typename T> xval { T& t; };` `template<typename T> xval<T> move(T&);`?

Answer (score 0):

First of all this code:

```
if(sizeof(it->second) == sizeof(MyObject)){
```

is equal to this:

```
if(sizeof(MyObject*) == sizeof(MyObject)){
```

so you either would not delete any, or if size of your object suddenly equal to a pointer you delete them all. In C++ there is no way by having only a pointer to determine if object is allocated dynamically or not. So you basically have 2 options:

```
1 Always own objects - when you have automatic aka scoped objects make a dynamically allocated copy.

2 Store additional information if you own the object or not, you can do that either by smart pointers or storing a flag together with pointer.
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution would be smart pointers. Since you use C++98, I've included a possible implementation.

```
template <typename t>
class auto_ptr
{
  private:
    t *_ptr;

  public:
    auto_ptr(t *ptr) : _ptr(ptr){};

    auto_ptr(auto_ptr<t> &lhs) : _ptr(lhs._ptr)
    {
        lhs._ptr = NULL;
    };

    ~auto_ptr()
    {
        if (_ptr != NULL)
        {
            delete _ptr;
        }
    };

    auto_ptr<t> &operator=(auto_ptr<t> &lhs)
    {
        _ptr = lhs._ptr;
        lhs._ptr = NULL;
        return *this;
    };

    t *get()
    {
        return _ptr;
    };
};
```

Comment: How is this effectively different from `std::auto_ptr` in `<memory>`, aside from missing a few key functions? Moreover, no one should use `std::auto_ptr`.

Comment: `std::auto_ptr` is not available in C++98. This is an implementation of a smart pointer for C++98 without move semantics.

Comment: `std::auto_pointer` was marked for death in c++11 and terminated in c++17. It was present in c++98.

Comment: Worth noting that neither this or `std::auto_ptr` has the smarts to handle a pointer to Automatic variable.